# How to launch Settings when ViewPager Fragment is shown?

Tags: android

I have a problem and to know more about the problem see the video , 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLZbakv2M7E&feature=youtu.be
I want to go to settings only when it is in the page today 
, but it is open random I do not know why.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    }








    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    return new Fragment_today();
                case 1:
                    return new Fragment_tomorrow();
                case 2:
                    return new Fragment_days();
                default:
                   return null;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "TODAY";
                case 1:
                    return "TOMORROW";
                case 2:
                    return "10 DAYS";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }







}
```

Fragment today

```
public class Fragment_today extends Fragment{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_today,container,false);
        Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(viewIntent);
        return v;
    }

}
```

I need help 4 days ago I'm trying to find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default behavior of a ViewPager initializes the Fragment currently shown, and also Fragments on either side.

In order to launch Settings only when the `Fragment_today` Fragment is shown, use a `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) { }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            if (position == 0) {
                Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(viewIntent);
            }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {  }
    });

}
```

Also, remove the Settings code from the Fragment:

```
public class Fragment_today extends Fragment{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_today,container,false);
        //Remove:
        //Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        //startActivity(viewIntent);
        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well I will not need this getitem??

Comment: You still need all the rest of your code, the only change needed is in onCreate(), so that is all I included in the answer.

Comment: But my step outside the application tells me there is a problem , @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

Comment: Keep the rest of your code exactly as you have it in the question.  The only change needed is the additional code in `onCreate()` of the Activity, and also the removal of the two lines of code in the Fragment.